# css :focus selector not working for input

Tags: html, css, angular8

I have a simple input of type text:

```
<input matInput type="text" placeholder="{{placeholder}}" class="input-field"
    [ngClass]="{'error': hasErrors}" [readonly]="isReadonly" [disabled]="isDisabled">
```

I've added this css rule for `readonly` state, using the `read-only` selectore:

```
.input-field {
    &:read-only {
        border-style: none;
    }
}
```

And I have this, which is correct:

[image]

The problem is that when I click on the placeholder, the focus event adds the border:

[image]

I need to get rid of that border on focus, so using `:focus` selector I've tried setting `border: none` but it doesn't work. I've tried:

```
.input-field {
    &:read-only,:focus {
        border-style: none;
    }
}
```

and

```
.input-field {
    &:read-only {
        border-style: none;

      &:focus {
         border-style:none;
      }
    }
}
```

but the border keeps appearing. I am using Chrome, but I've also tried Firefox and it doesn't work.

Comment: This is an outline, not a border.

Comment: @cloned still doesn't work with `outline:none`

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your focus:

```
{ outline-style: none; box-shadow: none; border-color: transparent; }
```